# correct url not showing up in iframe copied from embed button

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe, embed, jwplayer

I am working on a website in which proper url doesn't show up after copying from the embed button.

On clicking embed button(as shown below in an image), I am getting the following code inside iframe in which the value of **src is not correct**. It should be a proper video url.

```
<iframe src="//content.jwplatform.com/players/dalet_clips/35472P.mp4-88sIiZig.html" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

[image]

The snippets of code which I am using inside jwplatform.js is:

```
"sharing": {
    "code": "%3Ciframe%20src%3D%22http%3A//content.jwplatform.com/players/MEDIAID-6gKQPrHW.html%22%20width%3D%22480%22%20height%3D%22270%22%20frameborder%3D%220%22%20scrolling%3D%22auto%22%3E%3C/iframe%3E",
    "link": "http://content.jwplatform.com/previews/MEDIAID-6gKQPrHW"
},
```

**Problem Statement:**

Inside iframe src, I am getting the following code `//content.jwplatform.com/players/dalet_clips/35472P.mp4-88sIiZig.html` which is not correct. It should be proper url of the video. I am wondering what changes I need to do so that I get the complete **video url** inside **iframe src**.

Comment: What is the proper video URL?

Comment: The proper video url starts with `http://www` Sorry, I can't share the complete url.

Comment: Well, I have made an example for you, please see here-https://jsfiddle.net/rakibh/acw2qxdf/

Comment: Which version of JW player you are using - 7 or 8? What is your full JS code and where did you place it - in the document `head` or `body`? Do you use any relevant WordPress plugins?

Comment: The version of JWplayer which we are using is 8.7.5. I am not using any wordpress plugins. I am using Javascript code.

Comment: @SallyCJ  Do you have any idea how the `box picture` which I have pasted in the question above is getting created ? I looked into my JS code and I am not able to find anything.

Comment: @flash Check [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RvYGaB/left/?editors=1010#0) - I used JW player version 8.7.5 and a (dummy) video that's hosted on jwplatform.com.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing the `code` property in the `sharing` option in `jwplatform.js` to `encodeURIComponent` of whatever you want to be the exact `iframe` content

**Example:**
now you have the `code` as `%3Ciframe%20src%3D%22http%3A//content.jwplatform.com/players/MEDIAID-6gKQPrHW.html%22%20width%3D%22480%22%20height%3D%22270%22%20frameborder%3D%220%22%20scrolling%3D%22auto%22%3E%3C/iframe%3E`

Now try to decode this with `decodeURIComponent(code)` which evaluates to :

`<iframe src="http://content.jwplatform.com/players/MEDIAID-6gKQPrHW.html" width="480" height="270" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>`

You should try changing both `code` and `link` to your actual video link and code. just encode whatever content you want to be as code with `encodeURIComponent` or test the current one with `decodeURIComponent`, also keep the correct link in the `link` property.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you are making a mistake when you say that:

- `//example.com it is not a valid url...`  - Nope. It's absolutely valid url. Even, it's better type of url (called `schemeless` url,  without `http:`  prefixing).
- `...there should be video url (mp4) inside SRC...` -  No again. `iframes` are for web-pages (including `.html` pages), or not files (like `.mp4` or other file extensions), so that is the correct form of url.

**I think your problem is something different:**. Maybe that video file is deleted from server? Or something doesn't actually work on that destionation url? Check problems there.

p.s. you should have posted an example url which works (just change domain to `example.com` if you dont want to share it).